# Which of the following is a subgroup of group $G$?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the group of all positive integers less than or equal to $56$ and relatively prime to $56$. Let $S_1=\{1,9,17,25,33,41\}$ and $S_2=\{1,15,29,43\}$, then how do I check wether $S_1$ or $S_2$ is a subgroup of $G$? If I check the clousre property, then it becomes a long computation. Can someone give me a hint for a shorter method?

Comment: please someone give response

Comment: As someone suggested you, please be more clear...

Comment: Ok, I don't want you to loose hope on MSE forum.... let us do step by step... Do you know what is the group operation on $G$??

Comment: They probably expect you to use a calculator. Then it's not such a long calculation, especially if you have one with a mod operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set you're mentioning is a group with respect to “multiplication modulo $56$”, and it would be better to talk about the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}/56\mathbb{Z}$.

Questions about terminology aside, let's first see what's the order of this group: it is
$$
\varphi(56)=56\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)=24
$$
which unfortunately rules out neither $S_1$ nor $S_2$, which have cardinality a divisor of the group order. They also contain $1$, which is a necessary condition to be checked.

So we're left with a direct check. For a finite subset of a group, it is sufficient to check for closure under operations, but we might start with computing powers.

\begin{gather}
9\cdot 9=81\equiv 25\pmod{56}\\
25\cdot 9=225\equiv 1\pmod{56}\\
17\cdot17=289\equiv 9\pmod{56}\\
9\cdot17=153\equiv 41\pmod{56}
\end{gather}

Hey! We've found something! If $x=17$, we have $x^0=1$, $x^1=17$, $x^2=9$, $x^3=41$, $x^4=25$, $x^5=x^2\cdot x^3=33$ (as it's easily computed). Therefore $S_1$ *is* a subgroup.

Try the same with $S_2$.

Comment: now as 15.29$\equiv$33(mod 56) where 33$\notin$in G so S_2 is not a subgroup. Is it right

Answer (score 0):

" $G$ be the group of all positive integers less than equal to 56 and relatively prime to 56 " is not a proper word. You should have said $G$ be the group of units of the ring $\mathbb{Z}/56\mathbb{Z}$, then it is meaning full. To show that $S_i$ is a subgroup of $G$, you need to show that if $a,b \in S_i$, then $ab\equiv c \operatorname{ mod } 56$, for some $c \in S_i$ and if such $c$ does not exist, then it is not a subgroup.